# How to sort time in a table using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, html-table

I have table with time in it. When I use JavaScript to sort the column by clicking on header, it sorts the time in unusual way. I need to sort the time based on numbers that starts with `1:00:00 pm` to `12:00:00 am`.

```js
function sortTable(n) {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchcount = 0;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  //Set the sorting direction to ascending:
  dir = "asc"; 
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[n];
      /*check if the two rows should switch place,
      based on the direction, asc or desc:*/
      if (dir == "asc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      } else if (dir == "desc") {
        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
          //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
          shouldSwitch= true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
      //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
      switchcount ++;      
    } else {
      /*If no switching has been done AND the direction is "asc",
      set the direction to "desc" and run the while loop again.*/
      if (switchcount == 0 && dir == "asc") {
        dir = "desc";
        switching = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable"  class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" cellspacing="0"  width="100%">   
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th onclick="sortTable(0)" width="2%">T.No</th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(1)" width="2%">Bth</th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(2)" width="45%">Name</th>
      <th onclick="sortTable(3)">  In Time</th>

      <th>Undo/Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td  >1</td>
      <td><font color="#E91E63">A</font></td>
      <td >aaaaaa</td>
      <td >12:01:50 AM</td>
      <td>
        <a href="goingmrng.php?undoID=65" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"  ><i class="fa fa fa-undo"></i></a>
        <a href="goingmrng.php?removeIdS=65" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"  ><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td  >2</td>
      <td><font color="#E91E63">A</font></td>
      <td >ewwewewer</td>
      <td >12:01:57 AM</td>
      <td>
        <a href="goingmrng.php?undoID=64" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"  ><i class="fa fa fa-undo"></i></a>
        <a href="goingmrng.php?removeIdS=64" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"  ><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td><font color="#E91E63">A</font></td>
      <td >str</td>
      <td >01:00:33 PM</td>
      <td>
        <a href="goingmrng.php?undoID=63" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"  ><i class="fa fa fa-undo"></i></a>
 <a href="goingmrng.php?removeIdS=63" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"  ><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td><font color="#E91E63">A</font></td>
      <td >str</td>
      <td >01:00:31 PM</td>
      <td>
        <a href="goingmrng.php?undoID=62" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"  ><i class="fa fa fa-undo"></i></a>
        <a href="goingmrng.php?removeIdS=62" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"  ><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td><font color="#E91E63">A</font></td>
      <td >sdfasdi</td>
      <td >12:01:59 AM</td>
      <td>
        <a href="goingmrng.php?undoID=61" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"  ><i class="fa fa fa-undo"></i></a>
        <a href="goingmrng.php?removeIdS=61" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"  ><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td><font color="#E91E63">A</font></td>
        <td >w;e</td>
        <td >12:01:59 AM</td>
        <td>
          <a href="goingmrng.php?undoID=60" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"  ><i class="fa fa fa-undo"></i></a>
          <a href="goingmrng.php?removeIdS=60" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not valid HTML, you aren't closing your TRs, and you should be comparing a Date object rather than strings.

Comment: Remove AM and PM from the string and add 12 to the first two digits if it has a leading zero, `01:00:31 PM` becomes `13:00:31`. Workaround maybe but if it works... (You only need to make these changes to the matching condition, not directly to the table item for viewing)

Comment: @Pato, that is actually valid HTML. Those elements do not need to be closed in plain HTML. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) under "Tag Omission". In XHTML, yes, they would need to be closed.

Comment: Use moment.js for parsing and calculating date differences

Comment: Or sortable.js to do the whole thing for you. Why re-invent the wheel, answer: because it's off topic here :P